# Let 2Z = {2n : n ∈ Z}

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let 2Z = {2n : n ∈ Z}. Find a function $f: N \to 2Z$ that is 1-1 and
onto. Prove that your function is onto (no proof for 1-1 is required).

Comment: Please show some work so we can see where you need help or clear say what I  particular you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is fairly straightforward, but very creative. This is a variation on a classic problem in showing that the integers are countable.

It may help to rearrange the set $2\mathbb Z$ as $$0, -2, +2, -4, 4, -6, 6, \ldots.$$ Now, we may create a piecewise function $f(n) = \begin{cases}(n-1), & n=1,3,5,\ldots\\-n, & n = 2,4,6,\ldots\end{cases}$

Clearly $f(1) = 0$, $f(3) = 2$, $f(5) = 4$, and $f(2) = -2,$ $f(4) =-4$, and so on.

Now, we take a $y\in2\mathbb Z$, which implies $y$ is of the form $y=2m$, where $m\in\mathbb Z$. We must consider a few cases. If $y \ge0$, then take $x = y + 1 = 2m + 1$, which $x$ is still clearly a natural number. So $$f(x) = f(2m+1) = (2m + 1) - 1 = 2m = y\in2\mathbb Z.$$ Likewise, if $y < 0$, then take $x = -y = -2m$, which $x$ is still clearly a natural number. Then $$f(x) = f(-2m) = -(-2m) = 2m = y\in 2\mathbb Z.$$ Hence for all $y$ in $2\mathbb Z$, we have an $x$ in $\mathbb N$ such that $f(x) = y$.

Comment: Beware: the codomain in $2\mathbb{Z}$, not $2\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @b00nheT I apologize for that. Let me fix that really quick.

Comment: The Domain is $\mathbb{N}$. That's where the real difficulty of the exercise is.

Comment: @b00nheT Please look over it now. I feel like it is in order at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Think of a Table Tennis (Ping-Pong) game. $\mathbb{N}$ can be (for example) the counter for the number of exchanges between the players.